# DynamoDB updating fails with validation exception

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm using Dynamodb with the [DynamoDB npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb) and when I want to update data inside my Warehouse table I get the following error.
It will update my data but suddenly crashes with a nonsense error.
What's the problem?

```
ValidationException: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined; attribute value: :name
```

Code:

```js
let updateData = {
  customer: 'mrpen',
  name: warehouseInfo.name,
  street1: warehouseInfo.street1 ? warehouseInfo.street1 : 'N/A',
  street2: warehouseInfo.street2 ? warehouseInfo.street2 : 'N/A',
  city: warehouseInfo.city ? warehouseInfo.city : 'N/A',
  state: warehouseInfo.state ? warehouseInfo.state : 'N/A',
  country: warehouseInfo.country,
  zip: warehouseInfo.zip ? warehouseInfo.zip : 'N/A',
  contactName: warehouseInfo.contactName ? warehouseInfo.contactName : 'N/A',
  contactEmail: warehouseInfo.contactEmail ? warehouseInfo.contactEmail : 'N/A',
  contactPhone: warehouseInfo.contactPhone ? warehouseInfo.contactPhone : 'N/A',
  inventoryName: data[0].attrs.inventoryName,
};
const res = Warehouse.update(updateData, (err, res) => {
   if (err) {
    throw new Error('update warehouse failed!');
   } else {
    console.log(res);
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute is one of the [reserved words in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html).  You can either rename the attribute or define an expression attribute name to use in the place of the reserved word.

More info on [expression attributes in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html).